# How to get dynamic input box data using Thymeleaf?

Tags: jquery, spring-boot, thymeleaf

> I am using STS 3.9.0 Tool, my project based on Spring Boot, Thymeleaf, Mysql, Html-Bootstrap and JQuery.

I need to get the value of dynamicaly generated input boxes in thymeleaf..
**Explanation**

> 1.While Clicking Add Co-Owner button the Jquery will called and it will produces the input box
>
> 2.i need to get the values of the dynamically generated input box values in @controller page

**JQUERY - Dynamically generated input box code**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var max_fields      = 10; //maximum input boxes allowed
    var wrapper         = $("#adding_CownerInp"); //Fields wrapper
    var add_button      = $("#addButton_Cowner"); //Add button ID
    
    var x = 0; //initlal text box count
    $(add_button).click(function(e){ //on add input button click
        e.preventDefault();
        if(x < max_fields){ //max input box allowed
            x++; //text box increment now x=1 after x++ x=2,so next code 2%2==0 is true
            
            
            $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-row">'   
              +'<!-- Owner Name -->'
              +'<div id="TextBoxDiv'+x+'" class="form-group col-md-4">'
              +'<label for="cowner'+x+'">Name</label>'
              +'<input id="cowner'+x+'" th:field="*{listcoowner.coownername}" type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"></input>'
              +'</div>'
   
              +'<!-- Owner Phone Number -->'
              +'<div class="form-group col-md-4">'
              +'<label for="oph'+x+'">Phone Number</label>'
              +'<input id="oph'+x+'" th:field="*{listcoowner.cophone}" type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="+91-999-999-9999"></input>'
              +'</div>'
   
              +'<!-- Owner Email -->'
              +'<div class="form-group col-md-3">'
              +'<label for="email'+x+'">Email</label>'
              +'<input id="email'+x+'" th:field="*{listcoowner.coemail}" type="email"  class="form-control" placeholder="xyz@abc.com"></input>'
              +'</div>'
              +'<a href="#"class="remove_field col-md-1"> X </a>'
              +'</div>');
            
            
            
            
            
        }
    });
    
    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove(); x--;
    })
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Flat Addition Form</title>
<!-- Bootstrap Library CDN link -->
<link rel="stylesheet"
 href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css"
 integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M"
 crossorigin="anonymous">
 
<!-- this is for bootstrap spinner -->
<link href="../libs/jquery.bootstrap-touchspin.min.css">

</head>
<body>
<!-- Bootstrap/Jquery CDN library files -->
 <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
 <script
  src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.11.0/umd/popper.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-b/U6ypiBEHpOf/4+1nzFpr53nxSS+GLCkfwBdFNTxtclqqenISfwAzpKaMNFNmj4"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
 <script
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/js/bootstrap.min.js"
  integrity="sha384-h0AbiXch4ZDo7tp9hKZ4TsHbi047NrKGLO3SEJAg45jXxnGIfYzk4Si90RDIqNm1"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  
 <!--External Script for add/remove input -->
 <script src="../js/AddingCoOwnerInput.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <!-- Panel Starts -->
 <div class="panel panel-default">
  <div class="panel-heading">
   <h3 class="panel-title">Property Addition Form</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-body">
   <form action="/saveflat" th:action="@{/saveflat}" th:object="${flatDetails}" role="form" class="form-horizontal" id="propertyreg">
    <div style="width: 900px" class="container-fluid">

     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="societyname">Society Name</label> 
      <select class="form-control" id="societyname" th:field="*{entPropertyMaster}">
       <option th:each="propertydetails:${propertydetails}" th:value="${propertydetails}" th:text="${propertydetails.propertyname}"></option>
      </select>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="buildinglist">Building / Wing / Block *</label> 
      <select
       class="form-control" id="buildinglist" th:field="*{entPropertySub}">
       <option th:each="propertydetails:${propertydetails.blockListPropSub}" th:value="${propertydetails}" th:text="${propertydetails.blockname}"></option>
      </select>
     </div>

     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="Flat">Flat / Villa / Shop No *</label> 
      <input th:field="*{flatname}"
       type="text" class="form-control" id="flat" placeholder="Ex : 123..">
     </div>

    <div class="form-row">
     <!-- super buildup area -->
     <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="sbuild" class="col-form-label">Super Buildup
       Area</label> 
       <input th:field="*{superbuildup}" type="text" class="form-control" id="sbuild"
       placeholder="area sqft (Ex : 1200)"></input>
     </div>

     <!-- buildup area -->
     <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="build" class="col-form-label">Buildup Area</label> 
      <input th:field="*{buildup}"
       type="text" class="form-control" id="build"
       placeholder="area sqft (Ex : 1200)"></input>
     </div>

     <!-- carpet area -->
     <div class="form-group col-md-4">
      <label for="carpet" class="col-form-label">Carpet Area</label> 
      <input th:field="*{carpetarea}"
       type="text" class="form-control" id="carpet"
       placeholder="area sqft (Ex : 1200)"></input>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    <div class="form-row">
     <!-- No of bedrroms -->
     <div class="from-group col-md-6">
      <label for="bedrooms"> Number Of Bedrooms </label> 
      <input th:field="*{bedrooms}"
       id="bedrooms" type="text" value="" name="bedrooms" class="form-control">
     </div>

     <!-- No of bathrooms -->
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
      <label for="bathrooms">Number Of Bathrooms</label> 
      <input th:field="*{bathrooms}"
       id="bathrooms" type="text" value="" name="bathrooms" class="form-control">
     </div>
    </div>
     
     <!-- Parking Number -->
   <div class="form-row">
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
     <label for="parking">Parking</label>
     <input id="parking"  th:field="*{parking}" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex : A1 or 123.."></input>
     </div>
     
     <div class="form-group col-md-6">
     <label for="pfloor">Parking Floor</label>
     <input id="pfloor" th:field="*{parkingfloor}" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Ex : A1 or 123.."></input>
     </div>
   </div>
   
   <hr>
   
   <div class="form-row">
   <!-- Owner Name -->
   <div id="TextBoxDiv" class="form-group col-md-4">
    <label for="owner">Owner Name</label>
    <input id="owner" th:field="*{ownername}" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"></input>
   </div>
   
   <!-- Owner Phone Number -->
   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
   <label for="oph">Phone Number</label>
   <input id="oph" th:field="*{ownerphone}" type="text" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="+91-999-999-9999"></input>
   </div>
   
   <!-- Owner Email -->
   <div class="form-group col-md-4">
   <label for="email">Email</label>
   <input id="email" th:field="*{owneremail}" type="email" value="" class="form-control" placeholder="xyz@abc.com"
    aria-describedby="emailHelp"></input>
    <small id="emailHelp" class="form-text text-muted">We'll never share your email & Phone Number with anyone else.</small>
   </div>
   </div>
   
   <!-- co-owner -->
   
   <div id="adding_CownerInp" class="col-md-12">
   <label for="coowner" >Co-Owner</label>
   </div>
   
   <div class="form-group col-md-12">
    <input id="addButton_Cowner"  type="button" value="Add Co-Owner"  class="form-control col-md-4"></input>
   </div>
   
   <!-- submit form -->
   <div class="form-group">
   <center>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
   <button type="reset"  class="btn btn-danger">Reset</button>
   </center>
   </div>


<!-- Container fluid ends -->
    </div>
   </form>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The Controller Page Code**

```
//To save the flat registration details
    @PostMapping("/flatreg/saveflat")
    public ResponseMsg doSaveFlatDetails(@ModelAttribute EntFlatMaster flatDetails)
    {
        ResponseMsg responsemsg = new ResponseMsg();
        EntFlatMaster flatMaster = new EntFlatMaster();
        try {
            String logResponse = null;
            /*for Master*/
            if(flatDetails!=null)
            {
            flatMaster = serflatDetails.doSaveFlatDetails(flatDetails);
            /*for Log*/
            if(flatMaster!=null)
            {
                logResponse = doSaveLogFlatDetails(flatDetails,flatMaster.getPkflatid());
            }

            /*for response message to web for master and Log both are saved checking process*/
                if(logResponse.equals("saved"))
                {
                    responsemsg = new ResponseMsg("saved",flatMaster);
                }
                else
                {
                responsemsg = new ResponseMsg("failed",flatMaster);
                }

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
            e.printStackTrace();
            responsemsg = new ResponseMsg("failed",flatMaster);
        }
        return responsemsg;
    }
```

Please any one help me..Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

When you insert inputs with jQuery don't use `th:` attributes!

Thymeleaf is templating engine. While obtaining a view from server every `th:` elements are evaluated to plain HTML. That means in generated view none of element has `th:` attributes. So you can't simply add dynamically `th:` attributes with jQuery, because at this point it means nothing.

I assume that your `EntFlatMaster` class has a field like `List<CoownerClass> listcoowner`. In that case you can send data from your dynamically added inputs when you adjust you input generation code. In your script you should replace attributes like `th:field="*{listcoowner.cophone}` to the `name=listcoowner[index].field`. Should be fine when you replace `add_button` click callback with a following code:

```
$(add_button).click(function(e){ // on add input button click
    e.preventDefault();
    if(x < max_fields){ // max input box allowed

        $(wrapper).append('<div class="form-row">'
            +'<!-- Owner Name -->'
            +'<div id="TextBoxDiv'+x+'" class="form-group col-md-4">'
            +'<label for="cowner'+x+'">Name</label>'
            +'<input id="cowner'+x+'" name="listcoowner[' + x + '].coownername" type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Name"></input>'
            +'</div>'

            +'<!-- Owner Phone Number -->'
            +'<div class="form-group col-md-4">'
            +'<label for="oph'+x+'">Phone Number</label>'
            +'<input id="oph'+x+'" name="listcoowner[' + x + '].cophone" type="text"  class="form-control" placeholder="+91-999-999-9999"></input>'
            +'</div>'

            +'<!-- Owner Email -->'
            +'<div class="form-group col-md-3">'
            +'<label for="email'+x+'">Email</label>'
            +'<input id="email'+x+'" name="listcoowner[' + x + '].coemail" type="email"  class="form-control" placeholder="xyz@abc.com"></input>'
            +'</div>'
            +'<a href="#"class="remove_field col-md-1"> X </a>'
            +'</div>');

        x++; // text box increment now x=1 after x++ x=2,so next code 2%2==0 is true
    }
});
```

This solution will add new inputs and send proper data back to controller, **however it will also make field removal invalid!** If you want to keep fields removal you'll need to implement additional logic for `remove_field` callback, that would fix the indexes (fields should be indexed respectively from 0).

Alternatively, you can implement dynamically fields with help of thymeleaf and server side. Read [this piece of documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/thymeleafspring.html#dynamic-fields) to know how to do that.