# How to bind a dynamic child list using Thymeleaf and JQuery?

Tags: jquery, spring, thymeleaf

I am a complete newbie and I really hope you can help me!

I have two entities: Recipe and Product. The recipe object contains a list of products, the size of
which is "controlled" by the user - it changes based on how many products the user would like to
include.

This is my **Recipe Entity**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "recipes")
public class RecipeEntity extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;
    private String shortDescription;
    private String cookingInstructions;
    private Integer cookingTime;
    private Integer portions;
    private List<ProductEntity> products;
    
    //GETTERS, SETTERS
```

And this is the **Product Entity**:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "products")
public class ProductEntity extends BaseEntity {

    private String name;
    private Double quantity;
    private RecipeEntity recipe;
    
    //GETTERS, SETTERS
```

This is the **Thymeleaf** template:

```
 <h4>Products</h4>

 <div class="products" th:each="product, iterStat : *{products}">
   <div class="product row">


     <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
       Name
       <input th:field="*{products[__${iterStat.index}__].name}" id="product" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
     </div>

     <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">
       Quantity(grams)
       <input th:field="*{products[__${iterStat.index}__].quantity}" type="number" id="quantity" step="0.1" min="0" class="form-control form-control-lg" />
     </div>

   </div>
 </div>

 <button type="button" class="add-product btn btn-outline-secondary col-lg-12">+ Add another
   product
 </button>
```

And finally we have the **JQuery** function I wrote to add rows of products dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.add-product').click(function () {
        let newRow = jQuery('<div class="product row">' +
            ' <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">' +
            ' Name' +
            ' <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg"/>' +
            ' </div>' +
            ' <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">' +
            '  Quantity(grams)' +
            ' <input type="number" step="0.1" min="0"' +
            ' class="form-control form-control-lg"/>' +
            '</div>' +
            '</div>');

        $('.products').append(newRow)
```

Now the problem is I want to get all of the products along with the recipe on a post request and
save them to the DB together. The JQuery function works fine, it does append product rows,
however when i post the information to my RecipeController, the list of products is empty.

I would be really thankful if someone could show me the right direction, as I'm feeling completely lost on this one! Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've managed to solve my own problem with a bit more research, so I'm going to post the answer here in case someone finds it useful in the future.

Found this post really helpful -[How to get dynamic input box data using Thymeleaf?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47095430/how-to-get-dynamic-input-box-data-using-thymeleaf)

The thymeleaf template wasn't the problem as I initially thought.
There was an issue with the JQuery function that I've written.

Here is the working JQuery function that not only appends rows on the client side, but also transfers the parent object Recipe together with the child list Products to my RecipeController.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    let max_fields = 30;
    let index = 1;


    $('.add-product').click(function () {

        if (index < max_fields) {
            let newRow = jQuery('<div class="product row">' +
                ' <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">' +
                ' Name' +
                ' <input name="products[' + index + '].name" type="text" class="form-control form-control-lg"/>' +
                ' </div>' +
                ' <div class="col-lg-6 mb-3">' +
                '  Quantity(grams)\n' +
                ' <input name="products[' + index + '].quantity" type="number" step="0.1" min="0"' +
                ' class="form-control form-control-lg"/>' +
                '</div>' +
                '</div>');

            index++;

            $('.products').append(newRow)
        }

    });
});
```

One thing I would note is that it might be better to include label tags for name and quantity, however still even without them the code is working as expected!